# Python networks change color of nodes when using draw_network_nodes()

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

The goal is to obtain something similar to

[image]

To define the graph I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
    } 

MG = nx.DiGraph()
MG.add_edges_from([(start, stop, {'weigth' :  len(graph[start]) }) 
     for start in graph for stop in graph[start]])
```

and the code to plot it is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(MG,prog="twopi",root='1')
for n in MG.nodes_iter():
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(MG, pos,
        nodelist = [n],
        node_size = 2000 / float(len(MG[n[0]])+1),
        node_color = (len(MG[n[0]])+1),
        alpha = 1/float(len(MG[n[0]])+1),
        with_labels=True
                       )
xmax=1.1*max(xx for xx,yy in pos.values())
ymax=1.1*max(yy for xx,yy in pos.values())
plt.xlim(0,xmax)
plt.ylim(0,ymax)
plt.show()
```

There are 2 things here that I would like to know:

- how can I have the color node depending on the number of links each node has (i.e. `len(MG[0])`)?
- where are my labels?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?  You can use matplotlib's colormaps to map values to colors for the nodes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
    }

MG = nx.DiGraph(graph)


plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(MG,prog="twopi",root='1')

nodes = MG.nodes()
degree = MG.degree()
color = [degree[n] for n in nodes]
size = [2000 / (degree[n]+1.0) for n in nodes]

nx.draw(MG, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_color=color, node_size=size,
        with_labels=True, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, arrows=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect :) I want to set each nodes with a different alpha, so this is why I am looping the nodes instead of plotting them all together