# NetworkX in Python: Connect only values not keys

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I face a similar problem to the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378318/1252280), with almost the same data as described:

```
graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
}
```

However, if I feed this graph data into the linked script, it connects the keys of the data with values (e.g. "1" (key of the first row) is connected with "2" (key of the second row) of the next line in the data set).
<s>Clearing this up, at an example: I want to connect "1" of the first row with 2,3,4 of the first row, but not with 2 of the second row. Furthermore I want to connect all the values with each other, like 2 with 3 with 4 with 5 with 11 and so on.</s>

Is this anyhow clear?

All the remaining features of the linked script should be kept (such as adjusting the circle size of the nodes by their number edges, node labelling, etc).

**EDIT**
Thanks to Wayne Werner, I noticed an error in my explanation: Consider the following data of the data set stated above:

```
'3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
'5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
```

In this case I want to connect 3 with 6,7,66,77 but not 3 with 5.
Furthermore I want to connect 5 with 6,8,66,77.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, what you're asking for is to not do what the tool is designed to do. If you don't want '1' connected to '2' then **remove it from `['2', '3', '4']`**.

Comment: Thank you Wayne, for your response. However, I think I made myself not clear enough: "1" should be connected with ["2", "3", "4"] as well as the numbers in brackets should also be connected (also with the numbers of the next line in brackets). Values that should **not** be connected, are **"1"** [...] with **"2"** [...] of the next line in the data set. With this info, please re-read my initial question. If there are still things unclear, I will try to explain it again ;)

Comment: Just glancing at the code without reading the documentation I'm guessing that you specify connections via `'node': ['connection_1', 'connection_2', 'etc']`. If I'm reading you correctly, you want `'node1': ['node2'], 'node2':['fnord']`, yet you don't want node1 connected to node2. That doesn't make any sense to me. Do you understand networkx to work differently, or are you asking to do something besides that?

Comment: Thanks for your response again! I hope I understand networkX correctly^^ But yes, you got me right: I want to connect node with connection_1 and connection_2 but not node with node1 and not with node2. I enhance your example. Please consider the following data (in addition to your example): 'node2':['fnord', 'connection_1']. In this case I want to connect connection_1 from node with connection_1 from node2. Was this anyhow clear? (I also update the initial question now, since you showed me a mistake in my question^^)

Comment: I don't think that you do understand correctly, because you're asking for two different things at the same time. You have a graph of nodes. You specify nodes and the nodes you want to connect to. i.e. with `'1': ['2', '3', '4]` you're saying that you want 1 to be connected to 2, 3, and 4. Full stop. There is no anything else. If you add `'2': ['3', '4', '5']` then you're saying that you want 2 to be connected to 3, 4, and 5. There will *also* be a connection to `1`, because you *said you want 1 to be connected to 2 when you wrote `'1': ['2', '3', '4']`*.

Comment: Yes, apparently I misinterpreted the capabilities of networkX. I thought that it is possible to not connect the nodes with each other while only the connections are connected with each other. Seems like I asked the question about the wrong tool. Thanks for your kind clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is possible, I think you're just confused about how NetworkX graphs work. When you add a node to the graph, you pass in an ID to represent that node. Internally NetworkX uses this value to track individual nodes. When connect two nodes together, you pass two ids (representing nodes) to connect.

In your explanation of your problem you are wanting NetworkX to accept the same ID twice, but 'forget' that ID already represents a node. That's not possible.

You have two options:

1. Plot the indiviudal graphs individually (this allows you to re-used IDs at will)
2. Create unique IDs for each subgraph, but change the labels on the nodes.

The following is an example of the second approach. Here the key in the `graph` dictionary is used to create a unique ID set for each subgraph, e.g. `1_2`, `1_3`, `1_4`, etc. We store the unique IDs with the label, and apply these when creating the plot. That way it *looks* like multiple nodes have the same ID, even though they do not.

```
import networkx
from itertools import combinations

graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
}

g = networkx.Graph()
labels = {}

for k, vs in graph.items():
    vs.append(k)
    for a, b in combinations(vs, 2):
        # We're creating multiple 'subnetworks', so prefix the ids
        node_a = '%s_%s' % (k, a)
        node_b = '%s_%s' % (k, b)

        g.add_edge(node_a,node_b)

        # Store labels
        labels[node_a] = a
        labels[node_b] = b

# Draw the graph, replacing the labels to hide the unique IDs            
networkx.draw_spring(g, labels=labels)
```

This produces the following image, as you can see multiple nodes have the same label, even though behind the scenes they have distinct IDs.

[image]