# Model an undirected graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I tried to draw a "network graph" with networkX but was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431153/networkx-in-python-connect-only-values-not-keys), that this library is not intended for the purpose I want to use it for.

So summarizing the failed question linked above, I start with the data I want to plot and proceed with the actual question:

```
graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3' : ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
}
```

Considering this data as a defaultdict(list), the most left part is the key, and the list of the right side is a list of values to that key. What I want to achieve, is drawing a graph, similar to a network graph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376200/python-networks-change-color-of-nodes-when-using-draw-network-nodes/24378318#24378318): The more edges, the bigger the nodes, label the nodes, etc.

However, the difference is that I want to connect the keys, with the corresponding values (1 with 2, 1 with 3, 1 with 4) but **not** the keys with each other (**not** 1 with 2 with 3 with 5 with 4 with 7).

Image the data being Servers and clients. The keys are the servers, and the values are the clients. The servers (keys) are not connected to each other directly, they only share (sometimes) the same clients. As of the example above, server 3 and server 5 are both connected to the clients 6, 66 and 77. This is also the reason, why the clients (values) should not be connected with each other.

I was hopefully able to make my question clear^^

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - the graph will have two entities named 2, but one is a "server" and one is a "client", right?

Comment: Why have you asked the same question again? Update your original question with this information.

Comment: @ Elisha: Yes you are right. @ mfitzp: I didnt know, that I can change the title of a question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to use the same IDs for your servers and clients. NetworkX has no way to know if `2` refers to a client (that should be connected) or a server (that should not). To do what you're describing here, you just need to create a unique id for the servers. For example:

```
import networkx

graph = {
    '1': ['2', '3', '4'],
    '2': ['5','11','12','13','14','15'],
    '3': ['6','7','66','77'],
    '5': ['6', '8','66','77'],
    '4': ['7','66','77'],
    '7': ['9', '10']
}

g = networkx.Graph()

for k, vs in graph.items():
    server_id = 'server_%s' % k

    for v in vs:
        g.add_edge(server_id,v)

networkx.draw_spring(g)
```

This produces the following output:

[image: NetworkX plot]

To change the size of node by the number of edges, you need to calculate the size and pass it to `draw_spring`. To get the number of edges for a particular node you can call `g.edges(node)` e.g.

```
node_sizes = [150*len(g.edges(n)) for n in g.nodes()]
networkx.draw_spring(g, node_size=node_sizes)
```

Which should give you the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @mfitzp: This is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry for the messup with the "double-posts" I didn't know, that also the title of a question can be modified afterwards. Two things, before I finally mark it as correct answer: I needed to add a plt.show() at the end to actually show the figure. And secondly: Is it possible to adjust node size with "draw_spring" according to number of edges?

Comment: @user1252280 No problem! I've updated the answer with sized nodes based on the number of edges. The `plt.show()` is only needed if you're using one of the interactive backends for `matplotlib` so I left it out. You don't need it for example if you save the figure (`plt.gcf().savefig()`) or are using the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your final adjustments :)